# Find records without a prerequisite record in the dataframe

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, sqldf

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: `Timestamp`, `MMR_NBR` and `Action`

Action `DFV` must occur before `SAP Load` for all MMR_NBR instances. I want to extract the `SAP Load` instances that do NOT have a `DFV` action occurred before. I am using `sqldf` in `R` and I know that `R` uses `SQLite` database language so window functions are limited. I managed to get the records, but I am looking to see if there is a simpler and better way to write this with either `a SQL` query or any `R` package such as `dplyr`.

**Sample Data:**

```
 df5 <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 14L, 15L, 19L, 
20L), .Label = c("8/14/2018 11:22:18 AM", "8/14/2018 11:30:03 AM", 
"8/14/2018 11:32:26 AM", "8/14/2018 4:03:27 PM", "8/14/2018 4:04:05 PM", 
"8/14/2018 4:04:11 PM", "8/20/2018 4:02:00 PM", "8/20/2018 6:12:50 PM", 
"8/21/2018 9:56:51 AM", "8/21/2018 9:56:59 AM", "8/22/2018 10:43:45 AM", 
"8/22/2018 10:43:57 AM", "8/22/2018 4:34:53 PM", "8/23/2018 1:53:25 PM", 
"8/23/2018 1:53:36 PM", "8/23/2018 11:47:15 AM", "8/23/2018 12:23:44 PM", 
"8/23/2018 12:26:20 PM", "8/23/2018 2:38:59 PM", "8/23/2018 2:39:19 PM"
), class = "factor"), MMR_NBR = structure(c(12L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 
8L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("B00215", "B00216", "B00218", "B00219", "K00364", 
"K00625", "K00632", "K00642", "K00646", "W00362", "W00364", "W00365"
), class = "factor"), Action = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("DFV", 
"SAP Load"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Timestamp", "MMR_NBR", 
"Action"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

in the above sample data `8/14/2018 11:22:18 AM W00364  SAP Load` must be returned along with similar records as the result of the query.

**R Script:**

```
sql="SELECT DISTINCT Timestamp, MMR_NBR, Action FROM df5 WHERE (Action='DFV' OR Action='SAP Load') AND MMR_NBR<>''"
df5 <- sqldf::sqldf(sql)

sql="SELECT MMR_NBR,Action, COUNT(*) FROM df5 GROUP BY MMR_NBR HAVING COUNT(*)=1"
df6 <- sqldf::sqldf(sql)
```

Comment: Your `read.table` does not work as-is, my guess is that the tabs are not preserved in the SO question.

Comment: I used a function to select only 20 rows of my df and that function is not working I guess, somehow the combination of `dput` and `head` is not working

Comment: I've never seen `dput(head(x,n=20))` not work with a frame, that's odd. Perhaps you can replace it with the output from `write.csv(head(x))`? That's close enough for this data, I suspect.

Comment: `dput(head(x,n=20))` returns the entire x and not the top 20. I used the other one works, but what is the point? I cannot post it here

Comment: I understand that you do not want to post it here. I can't see how that would fail assuming that `x` is a frame, but ... given few other options, perhaps you can manually generate sample data, with `data.frame(...)`; often with this, sample data uses `letters`, `LETTERS` (even a subset of them, like `letters[1:3]`), and perhaps a random timeline with `set.seed(2); Sys.time() + runif(10, min=60, max=60*60*4)`. Make sure this contrived sample is relevant-enough that you can backport answers to your actual data.

Comment: All your columns are factors, so it lists all the levels even when you dput only the first 20. Do `dput(droplevels(head(x, 20)))`.

Comment: @iod nice one! I modified the sample data

Comment: Why *is* your timestamp a factor, by the way?

Comment: @iod I collect the records in Excel and then it is moved to Access and then I pull data from Access. The format in Excel is string so that should be the cause

Comment: I highly recommend `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `read.table` calls. This factors as default is ridiculous.

Comment: @iod I used `sqlQuery` function to pull data from the ACCESS database, however, I added this option and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

Step 1: turn Timestamp into an actual timestamp:

```
df5$Timestamp<- as.POSIXct(as.character(df5$Timestamp), format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Step 2:

```
require(dplyr)
df5 %>% group_by(MMR_NBR) %>%
arrange(Timestamp) %>% # Order by time
filter(Action=="SAP Load" & cumsum(Action=="DFV")==0) # Extract those cases where Action is "SAP Load" and the total of previous rows where Action was "DFV" is zero
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   MMR_NBR [4]
  Timestamp           MMR_NBR Action  
  <dttm>              <fct>   <fct>   
1 2018-08-14 11:22:18 W00364  SAP Load
2 2018-08-14 11:30:03 K00364  SAP Load
3 2018-08-14 11:32:26 K00364  SAP Load
4 2018-08-22 16:34:53 K00646  SAP Load
5 2018-08-23 11:47:15 B00218  SAP Load
```